# When is a Child process created in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I was going through some material on Coursera and they explained that when a subprocess command is used, a secondary environment is created for the Child process(Child process is used synonymously with subprocess in their example). The Parent process is locked until the Child process finishes, and then the flow of control is passed back to the Parent.

The example they gave was the following:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["sleep", "2"])
```

The above code was executed in the Python interpreter and after the sleep command was executed the Parent process (the python interpreter) was locked, until the Child process (the command `subprocess.run(["sleep", "2"])`) was finished.

The following code produces the same result (as far as I can tell)

```
import time

time.sleep(2)
```

The interpreter is locked until `time.sleep(2)` has completed.

Is a Child process also created in this instance? When is a Child process created in Python?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You have system functions to tell you when and if a child process is created; don't ask  us, ask you system.  Also, it seems that you could use more reading on the topic of multiprocessing.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I did not know I could use system functions to tell me when and if a child process was created. Which functions are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a child process is created for the execution of `time.sleep` is technically an implementation detail of the language. Any implementation worth its salt, such as the most common implementation called CPython, will not create a separate process just to sleep.